# Cannot compile plugin for a shared object

Tags: go, plugins, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, static-libraries

It looks like my issue is that GoLang includes the runtime in plugins so that they cannot be shared. I did

`go install -buildmode=shared std`

And then I try to compile my plugin as shared:

```
 go build -buildmode=plugin -linkshared /tmp/code_SUM.go
# command-line-arguments
runtime.islibrary: missing Go type information for global symbol: size 1
```

My code

```
# cat /tmp/code_SUM.go
package main
import (
        "fmt"
)
func SUM(x int, y int) int { fmt.Println("")
return x+y}
```

Is there any workaround or some way to patch / change the Go compiler / language in order to make my program happen?

Comment: See if this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18671) help.

Comment: @leafbebop Thanks but when I try downgrading as it says in one comment, the issue persists. I think that maybe one must propose a patch or change the actual behavior of the Go compiler / language in order to make my program happen. The reason I try to do it is that we have the intention to generate lots of plugins at runtime and we cannot let the generated objects become very large, because there might be thousands of them generated at runtime.

Comment: Hi Niklas, did you find a solution for your problem ? I'm running into the same with Go .12

Comment: @Oswin no solution, but there is more info at this link https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17150

Comment: Here is an interesting article describing the steps for this and the problem you'll run into : https://blog.ksub.org/bytes/2017/02/12/exploring-shared-objects-in-go/